# Why is the copy constructor called here?

Tags: c++, stdvector

Main.cc

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include "Student.h"


int main()
{
  Student matilda("100567899", "Matilda");
  Student joe("100234555", "Joe");
  Student stanley("100234888", "Stanley");
  Student timmy("100234888", "Timmy");



  vector<Student*> comp2404;

  comp2404.push_back(&matilda);
  comp2404.push_back(&joe);
  comp2404.push_back(&stanley);
  comp2404.push_back(&timmy);

  vector<Student> vect2;
  vect2.push_back(matilda);
  vect2.push_back(timmy);

  cout<<"all done"<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**Student.cc**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

#include "Student.h"


Student::Student(string nu, string na)
    : number(nu), name(na)
{ 
  cout<<"-- Student default ctor "<<name<<endl;
}

Student::Student(const Student& stu)
{
  name   = stu.name;
  number = stu.number;
  cout<<"-- Student copy ctor "<<name<<endl;
}

Student::~Student()
{ 
  cout<<"-- Student dtor"<<endl;
}

string Student::getName() const { return name; }

void Student::setName(string n) { name = n; }

ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, Student& stu)
{
  output<<"Student:  "<<stu.number<<"  "<<stu.name<<endl;
  return output;
}
```

The output is:

```
-- Student default ctor Matilda
-- Student default ctor Joe
-- Student default ctor Stanley
-- Student default ctor Timmy

-- Student copy ctor Matilda
-- Student copy ctor Timmy
-- Student copy ctor Matilda
-- Student dtor
all done
-- Student dtor
-- Student dtor
-- Student dtor
-- Student dtor
-- Student dtor
-- Student dtor
```

Why does `vect2` call the copy constructor? Can't the vector just store the actual objects(Matilda and Timmy)? Also, why is it that "Matilda" was called twice in `vect2`?

Comment: What do you mean by "the actual object"?

Comment: As for the extra "Matilda", I suggest you check that you don't have an extra one at that point in your code, recompile, and run it again.

Comment: @ooga in the code, only two objects were pushed to 'vect2'

Comment: I'll suggest you to check the output of the program again. Maybe something is missing in the output?

Comment: @Manuel you may find the initial capacity of `vect2` interesting, as well as its capacity after the push of both objects. Try `std::cout << vect2.capacity() << '\n';` initially, and again after each push. Then rerun your code, but immediately after the decl put a `vect2.reserve(2);`

Comment: @Manuel, Did you check your actual code, recompile, and run again?

Comment: @ooga Yeah, the weird thing is that it called "Matilda"'s copy constructor and destructor

Comment: @ooga: The output he is getting is in line with what would be expected with the shown code.

Comment: If you want to minimize copies, take a look at the [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) member function, and if you are using C++11, [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).

Comment: You may also want to look into defining a *move constructor*; often a move is a nicer thing to do than a copy-construct plus destruct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the push_back method in vector receives a reference, it needs to copy the value passed by parameter, if not, think of what will happen in this case, when the local variable 'matilda' goes out of scope before 'v' is accessed:

```
int main()
{
    std:vector<Student> v;
    {
         Student matilda("100567899", "Matilda");
         v.push_back(matilda);
    }
    // Try to access the first element of 'v' here:
    std::cout << v[0].getName() << std::endl;
}
```

That is why it is calling the copy constructor.

Now, each time std::vector needs to increase the size of its internal array it will copy the elements from one array to other, then calling the copy constructor again. That's why Matilda is copied the second time. (Try commenting the line `vect2.push_back(timmy);` and see how Matilda is only copied once).

Comment: *"each time it needs to move one element from one position to other inside its internal 'array'"* -- That's not happening. It is being copied from one internal array, to a new one when a reallocation happens due to insufficient capacity.